# Two point boundary value in C++

Tags: c++, math, numerical-methods, differential-equations

Boost.Odeint does not have code for the solution of the Two point boundary value problem (TPBVP). I was not able to find any C++ implementation. Do you know of any open source implementation?

Thank you!

Comment: I expected downvotes -.- For those downvoting: I have already used Google and couldn't find anything...
Downvoting and not saying why you downvote only leads to stop using stackoverflow.

Comment: Did you check [this](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/fem1d_bvp_linear/fem1d_bvp_linear.html)?

Comment: Yes, I saw that one but it is only for 1 dimension. I am looking for something generic.

Comment: @JaviV I personally don't get what's wrong with this question so I upvoted it for ya. I know I hate it when my questions are downvoted without me being given a reason why and a chance to correct the downvotes.

Comment: @BrentonHorne thanks for your comment, good to see there are still some good users around here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the numerical recipes:

http://apps.nrbook.com/empanel/index.html

Chapter 18 talks about BVPs. There won't be one size fits all solutions though, you should give a bit more information about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at it. To explain the specific problem I have requires a lot of details, so I preferred to keep the question short :)

Comment: Solving BVPs is not easy so you will have to provide details if you expect help. Also please accept the answer if you ended up finding it helpful :)

Comment: Oops, yes, sorry. It was very useful. I am not very experienced with BVPs but after reading a lot I realized it was not that easy as I thought in the beginning. Thank you for your help :)